# in AS3 how would you sort read xml data by information in one of the nodes that is numerical?

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

In my xml one of my nodes reflects time. The time is minutes, seconds, and milliseconds '00:00.0'. I want to create a list of 10 xml nodes that have the shortest or quickest time (i.e. the lowest number). For example, the list contains 20 entries. The highest of the times is 00:06.9. and the lowest or fastest is 00:02.3. With the other numbers in between. How would I get a list of  the fastest 10 entries shown first.

```
Example XML
----------
<users>
<user>
<id>6546543654</id>
<time>00:06.9</time>
</user>
</users>
```

Answer (score 0):

Better saving times in milliseconds for comparing. For displaying the time you can format it.

Filter a xmllist with the times. Iterate it and push every item to an array.
After that sort the array. And do now with this array whatever you want.
A little example:

```
var xml:XML = 
<users>
    <user>
        <id>6546543654</id>
        <time>6900</time>
    </user>
    <user>
        <id>6546543655</id>
        <time>7000</time>
    </user>
    <user>
        <id>6546543656</id>
        <time>3000</time>
    </user>
    <user>
        <id>6546543657</id>
        <time>10000</time>
    </user>
</users>;

function parseIntoArray(xml:XML):Array{
    var arr:Array = []; 
    for each(var item:XML in xml.children()){
        arr.push({id:item.id, time:item.time});
    }
    return arr;
}

function printArray(arr:Array):void{
    for(var i:int=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        trace(arr[i].id, arr[i].time);
    }
}

var dataArray:Array = parseIntoArray(xml) ;
printArray(dataArray);  
dataArray.sortOn("time", Array.NUMERIC );
printArray(dataArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to not work on the XML directly.

XML is a serialized format of data, but you are looking for functionality.

Create objects based on the list, with appropriate classes (hint: Date) that allow you to easily compare the objects. Then sort them (or whatever you want to do) and write them back to XML.